# Не работают одновременно два js скрипта

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Подключаю в одном файле spritespin.js и https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.20/jquery.fancybox.min.js". Fancybox работает, а 3d, реализуемое с помощью spritespin.js, не показывается.

Код ошибки:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toolbar' of undefined
    at n.init (jquery.fancybox.min.js:12)
    at new n (jquery.fancybox.min.js:12)
    at HTMLDocument.onInit.fb (jquery.fancybox.min.js:12)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:5206)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5014)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js:8201)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js:8269)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:362)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:157)
    at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js:8268)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы они работали вместе?

Comment: ошибка говорит, что проблема как раз в fancybox

Comment: проверьте какие  еще скрипты нужны для этих проекток.

Comment: по отдельности они работают, а совместно - нет